# Getting error when trying to subscribe to function in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I  am getting error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
I have a simple api that returns a Vehicle, which has these fields

```
    public int Id {get ;set;}
    public int ModelId { get; set; }

    public KeyValuePairResource Model { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePairResource Make { get; set; }
    public bool IsRegistered { get; set; }

    public Contact ContactInformation { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdate {get; set;}
    public ICollection<KeyValuePairResource> Features  { get; set; }`
```

Now, In the angular front end, I have a simple get method that calls this api endpoint

```
getVehicle(id) {
   return this.http.get('/api/vehicles/'+ id);


}
```

in my angular component onInit function i am doing

```
ngOnInit() {

this.makes = this.vehicleService.getMakes();
this.features = this.vehicleService.getFeatures();
// this.vehicle is defined as any 
this.vehicleService.getVehicle(this.vehicle.id)
.subscribe(res=> { this.vehicle = res ;});
```

}

and finally the code where the program fails seems to be in the HTML

```
<div class="form-group"><label for="ContactName">Name</label>
        <input id= "ContactName" required #name="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "vehicle.ContactInformation.name " name = "name"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name.valid && name.touched">Please enter Name</div>
```

I have seen similar problems on stack, but none of them have actually solved my problem.
I know that the function is asynchronous and the webpage tries to load it before the async function returns completely. But i have other parts in the code where i try to access things like in

```
<div *ngFor="let f of features"class="checkbox">
<label for="feature{{f.id}}" (change) = "onFeatureToggle(f.id , $event)">
    <input type="checkbox" id="feature{{f.id}}">{{f.name}}
</label>
```

and that doesn't seem to crash.
I am really confused. I think i have given what is necessary for this problem, but please tell me if i need to provide more code.
The worst part is, i actually got it to work by accident, and the code in onInit didn't look any different.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? You are accessing this.vehicle.id value - is this initialized?

Comment: yes, the vehicle id is initialized correctly, and if i try to console.log () in the .subscribe function, it returns the correct object

Comment: Is vehicle.ContactInformation set correctly? If ContactInformation is undefined that would explain the error

Comment: my vehicle object is defined as 
  vehicle :any = {
  
    features : [],
    ContactInformation:{}
  };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your component the expression `vehicle.ContactInformation.name` is not defined, because `ContactInformation` is undefined. This will cause an error in the template.

Because you are using `ngModel` with two way binding, you cannot use `vehicle.ContactInformation?.name`. You should try to first check if it exists with an `*ngIf`:

```
<input *ngIf="vehicle.ContactInformation" 
       id="ContactName" required #name="ngModel"
       type="text" class="form-control"
       [(ngModel)]="vehicle.ContactInformation.name" name="name">
```

Or you can not use two way binding and split it up:

```
<input
       id="ContactName" required #name="ngModel"
       type="text" class="form-control"
       [ngModel]="vehicle.ContactInformation?.name" 
       (ngModelChange)="vehicle.ContactInformation ? vehicle.ContactInformation.name = $event : null"
       name="name">
```

The reason it works with your `*ngFor` loop, is because the `*ngFor` checks if the passed array is defined, if it's not, it doesn't loop.

You can also try to initialize your object beforehand:

```
vehicle = {
  id: this.route.snapshot.params.id,
  features: [],
  contactInformation: {}
};
```

But I think the issue you are having, is that it's `contactInformation` and not `ContactInformation`. The rest of your code seems to be using lowercase like `features` and `id`, I don't see why just `ContactInformation` is with a capital

Comment: is there a way that i can define ContactInformation?
my vehicle object is defined as
  vehicle :any = {
  
    features : [],
    ContactInformation:{}
  };
Also what if i want to show the field, even when the name is not there?

Comment: @DAoliHVAR can you show in your question where and how you defined the vehicle, because what you just showed, does not include the `.id`

Comment: i have route.params.subscribe(p => {this.vehicle.id = +p['id']}), and this works, i have checked it

Comment: @DAoliHVAR I've updated my answer, I think your issue is that the request is returning `contactInformation`, not with a capital C

Comment: Yes that was it, Thank you so much, I can't believe i wasted so much time on such a small problem. Lesson learned i guess, this will help me find such problems much faster in the future. I am new to c# programming, and learned to use pascal case, but in angular that doesn't seem to be the standard. Again, thank you, I guess all that's needed to solve a problem is a fresh set of eyes